# How to expose docker containers to the internet if they share the host port?

Tags: docker, docker-container, docker-network

I am using docker for windows. There are 2 containers running Windows IIS on ports listed below:

```
Container 1: 0.0.0.0:50095->80/tcp
Container 2: 0.0.0.0:50093->80/tcp
```

My host machine IP is 192.168.25.110

As shown above, both containers map to port 80. So when external users browse to 192.168.25.110:80, which of the 2 containers will be accessed? Is there a deterministic behavior?

Comment: how are you running the containers ? which command

Comment: Command: `docker container run -d -P windows/servercore/iis:windowsservercore-ltsc2019`

Comment: you should use it like this: `docker run  -p 80:80`

Comment: Port 80 won't reach either container: the _first_ number in that output is the host port, so port 50095 reaches one container and 50093 the other.

Comment: David - so does it allow at most 1 host port to point at 1 container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David mentioned in the comments, you are backwards on your port mappings.  Based on what you've given, for example, you would navigate to http://192.168.25.110:50095/ in order to reach Container1.

That's probably not what you want as you likely want to use the default HTTP port (80).

You should look into a reverse proxy solution for your situation.  The reverse proxy will listen on port 80 for ALL traffic and then decide (based on configuration) which container to send the request to.

Traefik is a popular solution for this.  Traefik listens on port 80 and then you can configure it to route traffic to different containers based on rules.

You could do something like:

- `http://192.168.25.110/container1` =>  Container1
- `http://192.168.25.110/container2` =>  Container2

OR

- `http://container1.docker.local` =>  Container1
- `http://container2.docker.local` =>  Container2

Take a look at Traefik's quick start guide: https://docs.traefik.io/getting-started/quick-start/